# Update with percentage calculation on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1093

I have a table like this:

```
ItemID      PersonID  Score      Percentage
==========================================
1             1       10         [ = 10 / 10+30 = 25%]
1             2       30         [ = 30 / 10+30 = 75%]
2             1       20         [ = 20 / 20+40 = 33%]
2             2       40         [ = 40 / 20+40 = 67%]
```

The data on "Percentage" is not entered but is auto-calculated at certain time interval.
The calculation is Percentage = Score / Total Score of the ItemID

Instead of using "SELECT-do the maths-UPDATE" method, I'm trying to write a single SQL to update the "Percentage".

What I tried is like this:

```
UPDATE tb_temp AS t1 
    SET t1.Percentage = 
        CEIL( t1.Score / 
            (SELECT SUM(t2.Score) FROM tb_temp AS t2 WHERE t2.ItemID = t1.ItemID)
        );
```

But it doesn't work.(Error Code : 1093 You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause).

Any idea?

Comment: With `CEIL()`, you will get `34%` and `67%` for `ItemID=2`.

Comment: thx for reminding....I would use ROUND() instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tb_temp AS t1 
    SET t1.Percentage = 
        CEIL( t1.Score / 
            (SELECT SUM(t2.Score) FROM tb_temp AS t2 left join tb_temp AS t3 on t2.ItemID = t3.ItemID)
        );
```

Comment: Have you even try your statement?

Comment: And I repeat... Have you event try your "corrected" statement?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
  UPDATE tb_temp t1 
     JOIN (SELECT ItemId, SUM(t2.Score) TotalScore
           FROM tb_temp 
           group by ItemId) t2 ON t2.ItemID = t1.ItemID
  SET t1.Percentage = CEIL( t1.Score / t2.TotalScore)
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't2.Score' in 'field list'

Comment: Assuming @Michael Pakhantsov wanted to write: `update tb_temp t1 inner join (select tt.ItemID, sum(tt.Score) TotalScore from tb_temp tt group by tt.ItemId) t2 using (ItemID) set t1.Percentage = CEIL(t1.Score / t2.TotalScore * 100)` (assuming `Percentage int`).